# Has anyone used omniauth with rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, omniauth

I am new to Rails and I am trying to use omniauth with rails 2.3.8. I
couldn't find any tutorial for this version of rails so I referred to
http://blog.railsrumble.com/blog/2010/10/08/intridea-omniauth.

I added the initializer as follows:

### omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter = { 
    :consumer_key => 'xxxxxx', 
    :consumer_secret => 'xxxxxx' 
}
```

After this step if I try to hit the URL '/auth/twitter' then I get "No
route matches "/auth/twitter" with {:method=>:get}".

Has anyone used omniauth with rails 2.3.8?

Comment: What are the routes `rake routes` lists ?

Comment: I had not added anything to the routes file as the tutorial said that once you put the initializer in place /auth/twitter should take you to the twitter page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OmniOauth is a Rack::Middleware. So you need use it like that.

So you need add like that :

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter = { 
    :consumer_key => 'xxxxxx', 
    :consumer_secret => 'xxxxxx' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! My initializer file (omniauth.rb) now looks like this:
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter, 'xxxconsumer_keyxxx', 'yyyconsumer_secretyyy'

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works for me in rails 2.3.8

omniauth.rb:

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook,
    "key", "secret", 
    :scope => %(email user_birthday publish_stream offline_access),
    :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => '/etc/ssl/certs'}}
end
```