# How to Use OmniAuth Properly with Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, omniauth, middleware

I am trying to use an OmniAuth (0.2.6) strategy for my application.  The architecture is Rails 2.3.10 and Rack is version is 1.1 (this version or higher is required for OmniAuth).  A problem that occurs is Rails doesn't recognize my redirect to "/auth/provider".  The actual error message is "No route matches "/auth/casport".  Even though that error gets thrown, the code seems to execute past that point up to this error: "request.env['omniauth.auth']", which I'm pretty sure means it doesn't recognize the "omniauth.auth" key for the env hash.  I have a feeling that OmniAuth isn't being loaded properly.  I've tested the same strategy and code base with Mongrel and Webrick, and I get identical error messages.

Here is my OmniAuth initializer (config/initializers/omniauth.rb):

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :casport, :setup => true
end
```

I definitely have routes in places for auth/casport/setup and auth/casport/callback.

I've also tried this approach: [How do you implement OmniAuth on Rails 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165544/how-do-you-implement-omniauth-on-rails-2-2)

```
config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :casport, :setup => true
end
```

by placing that middleware code in the config/environments/development.rb file.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I could be doing incorrectly?  Thanks!

**Edit:** I've also tried this approach [Has anyone used omniauth with rails 2.3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062674/has-anyone-used-omniauth-with-rails-2-3-8)

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Strategies::Casport = {
  :setup => true
}
```

and that returns a read error: "NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for #Hash...

**Edit 2:** I've upgraded to Rails 2.3.10 as OmniAuth isn't compatible with Rails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an issue on OmniAuth's Github page https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/397, with the above details and this is the response from Michael Bleigh, the creator of OmniAuth:

"OmniAuth has never officially supported Rails 2.3.x -- I've heard that some people have had luck with it but it's not something that is guaranteed. Sorry!"

So it looks like the methods I posted above may work for some folks.  To guarantee correct operation, Rails 3 is needed.