# undefined method `action' for a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I am using omniauth in my web application. I am trying to catch omniauth failure (Permission denied Error)  exception. I referred this post.
[How to rescue OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737200/how-to-rescue-omniauthstrategiesoauth2callbackerror)

I have this code in my initializers.

```
  OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
  UserSessionsController.action(:omniauth_failure).call(env)
  end
```

I am getting this error:

```
  undefined method `action' for UserSessionsController:Class
```

Can anyone help me out? I am using ruby 1.8.7  and rails 2.3.8

Comment: The post you are referring to is speaking of a RoR 3 application, while you working on a RoR 2 application. I guess that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this functionality in RoR2 ?

Comment: It would appear that `OmniAuth` doesn't have a version that is designed to work on Rails 2.3.x (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686780/how-to-use-omniauth-properly-with-rails-2).

Answer (score 0):

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
  # https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/d02f9d58f70f132c856199470f94b93c852d9bb0/lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb
  # line no 29,30,31
end
```